# Android - Can't resolve ?colorPrimaryDark in drawable xml file

Tags: android, xml, themes

I use different themes (5 different colors) for a project. I've created an xml file for a drawable background item and this background item have to have corresponding theme color. I get an exception when program stars:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/badge_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020061
```

/drawable/badge_background.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:thickness="10dp"
    android:innerRadius="0dp">

<solid
    android:color="#444" />

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="?colorPrimaryDark" />

<padding
    android:top="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

AndroidStudio doesn't give any errors or warnings about the issue. It just compiles perfectly but I get the exception on runtime. And colorPrimaryDark is defined with in my all themes.

How to overcome of this problem?

EDIT: Some people have been asking why you just don't use colorPrimaryDarkRed. Because again, it should have the "color of the theme", not red all the time. Here's my styles.xml file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryRed</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkRed</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccentRed</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeBlue" parent="AppTheme" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

EDIT2: badge_cart_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?colorPrimaryDark"
android:id="@+id/rl_my_card">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_order"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/if_cart_1543351" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_order_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/iv_order"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iv_order"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/badge_background"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_order"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_order"
    android:text="@string/my_cart_capitalize"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Change **?colorPrimaryDark** to **@color/colorPrimaryDark**

Comment: colorPrimaryDark is not defined. I'm using colors in color.xml in colorPrimaryDarkRed, colorPrimaryDarkGreen etc..

Comment: You say colorPrimaryDark is not defined then why do you use it there?

Comment: you should add @color  Ex:android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDarkRed"

Comment: @AyushKhare I've edited the question.

Comment: Your edit makes things more clear, I tried your code it's working for me. Can you add your xml code where you set `badge_background`

Comment: @AyushKhare edited.

Comment: Your `@drawable/if_cart_1543351` is an image or xml?

Comment: It's a PNG file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've finally found the answers myself!

So here's the thing. We can not directly reference to a *@color* on pre-lollipop devices. So what I have done is that I've created 5 different **badge_background.xml** file for each color and then I've created an attribute named "badge_background". I've referenced this to corresponding drawable xml using styles. Here's the work:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppThemeOrange" parent="AppTheme" >
    name="badge_background">@drawable/badge_background_orange</item>
</style>
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
    <attr name="badge_background" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

**TextView that causes exception**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_order_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/iv_order"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iv_order"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="?attr/badge_background"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

It's simple yet it took me 2 hours to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:useLevel="false"
    android:thickness="10dp"
    android:innerRadius="0dp">

<solid
    android:color="#444" />

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

<padding
    android:top="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

Note :Try this